# Docker-compose recently unable to expose port 80

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

A small project of mine used the following docker-compose script for local development

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  php:
    image: php:8.2.4-apache
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/

  composer:
    image: composer:2.5.4
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
```

However lately when spinning up the primary container with `docker-compose run --rm php` port 80 is not mapped and `docker-compose ps` shows the following output:

[image: docker-compose ps output]

When running what should be the identical configuration directly within docker however everything works just fine

The only difference that I can see is that when running `docker ps` the `docker-compose` run seems to not be mapping the port at all for some reason. This is a recent development and this configuration worked fine for months.

[image: missing-local-map]

As demonstrated below, the logs from the container itself are identical.

[image: side-by-side output]

Is there any new behavior causing `docker-compose` not to map the port correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `--service-ports` was introduced and enforced recently. This is required now to auto-mount ports.